# extract a html table data to csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

how to extract this html data table to csv file.

```
<table id="parts" class="parts-first horizontal">
    <tbody>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="score"><span class="rb">69</span</td>
                <td class="score part"><span class="p1_home">31</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td class="score"><span class="rb">63</span></td>
                <td class="score part"><span class="p1_away">17</span></td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

that gives those two lines data:
    
        
                
                    69
                    31
                
                
                    63
                    17
                
        
    

note that those data are refreshable,they change every one minute, so my csv file must contain something like that:

11,23
11,34

19,39 
22,30

22,99
22,33

...

Comment: The CSV file has to be saved on a server (and then downloaded if you need it). But Javascript cannot edit/update files on your machine. So is this what you need? The Javascript gets these values from the DOM, sends them to a server, and then update the CSV file on the server?

Comment: @blex he/she didn't ask that they are saved on their machine - just extract them from the HTML

Comment: this will be a second issue :)now all  i want is the javascript code

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the code to get the data and form a CSV string from it, there you go. It outputs it to the console, but you might instead update the actual file with Ajax and PHP.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

function init(){
  var table = document.getElementById('parts');
  var csvString = table2csv(table, ',', false);
  console.log( csvString ); // Now you can save this string in a variable, or send it
}

function table2csv(table, delimitor, trailing){
  var data = '',
      rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for(var i=0, l=rows.length; i<l; i++){
    var line = [],
        cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var j=0, k=cells.length; j<k; j++){
      var value = cells[j].textContent.trim(' ');
      line.push(value);
    }
    data += line.join(delimitor) + (trailing?delimitor:'') + "\n";
  }
  return data + "\n\n";
}
```

```html
The CSV should appear in your console.
<table id="parts" class="parts-first horizontal">
    <tbody>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="score"><span class="rb">69</span</td>
                <td class="score part"><span class="p1_home">31</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td class="score"><span class="rb">63</span></td>
                <td class="score part"><span class="p1_away">17</span></td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```